# How to open a Paddle Classic sandbox account?

Tags: payment-gateway, sandbox, paddle

I need to open a Paddle Classic (not Paddle Billing) sandbox account to support a legacy service.

I have searched their website and docs, but found no clue on how to do it. As far as I see, one can only create a Paddle Billing sandbox account.

I've emailed their support, but have not received a reply in 2 days.

Has anyone had the same issue?

How do you deal with Paddle developer support?

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask their support team to change this.

They can also enable a toggle button for your account so that you can switch backwards and forwards between the old Classic and new Billing systems.
I find this best for my Sandbox account and any Classic accounts that I will be transitioning to Billing.